# Calculating SHA1 in PHP similar to CC_SHA1_Update in C

Tags: php, c, sha1

So I have an application in C that is transmitting data over the internet to a PHP page. The C implementation for my hash is:

```
    CC_SHA1_CTX ctx;
    CC_SHA1_Init(&ctx);
    CC_SHA1_Update(&ctx, ciph_right,20);
    CC_SHA1_Update(&ctx, _keyRight, 20);
    CC_SHA1_Final(digest, &ctx);
```

Where ciph_right and _keyRight are simply 2 byte arrays of length 20.  How can I achieve this similar implementation for PHP so I'm getting the same result?

I don't hav the CC_SHA1_Update function in PHP, I simply have sha1().  And unfortunately I'm not 100% certain what CC_SHA1_Update actually does. I thought it simply combined the two byte arrays + took a hash of them together, but this appears to not be the case.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sha1` function takes a complete string and derives a SHA1 hash from that complete string.

A bit of Googling suggests that the C calls to `CC_SHA1_Update` are just adding more data to be hashed.

You therefore have two options.

1. Just concatenate all the data together and then call `sha1` on it.
2. Use the (standard) [hash extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) in streaming mode:

.

```
$h = hash_init('sha1');
hash_update($h, 'some data');
hash_update($h, 'some more data');
$final_hash = hash_final($h);
```

`$final_hash` should then contain `fa978155004254c23f9cf42918ad372038afcaf5`, which happens to be the same hash as the string '`some datasome more data`'.